# Найти диапазон по числу с ближайшим min к этому числу и ближайшим max к этому числу

Tags: excel, excel-формулы, формулы

Подскажите каким образом можно вернуть значение удовлетворяющее следующему условию:

Имеется число. Необходимо найти диапазон, в который это число попадает, вернув значение соответствующие этому диапазону, при этом диапазон выбирается из условия.
Выглядит следующим образом:

```
   A           B            C
Диапазоны     Условие     Значение диапазона
1.12230        21          II
2.51764        21          II

3.59535        21          III
4.60691        21          III

5.80136        21          IV
6.95233        21          IV

7.121573       22          II
8.212050       22          II

9.235020       22          III
10.260778      22          III

11.331025      23          I
12.387000      23          I

13.400000      23          II
14.531143      23          II
```

Например Число=92333, условие = 21. Анализируя список диапазонов с условием 21, находим, что этому числу удовлетворяет диапазон 5-6, а значит надо вывести IV

**UPD**

```
 A           B            C
Диапазоны     Условие     Значение диапазона
1.12230        21          II
2.51764        21          II

3.51765        21          III
4.60691        21          III
```

Получается должен обрабатываться массив, а не первое входящее число.
Т.е прогнать сначала через диапазон 1-2, потом 3-4 и т.д

Comment: Возможен ли вариант, когда к подходящему диапазону не подходит условие (пример: Число=92333, условие = 22)? Или вариант, когда разные числа в столбце 3 (пример: диапазоны 5 , 6, но в С у них  разные значения). Если да, то как быть в этом случае?

Comment: @vikttur возможен, можно указать "нет данных"

Comment: @vikttur Со вторым Вашим примером такого невозможно, т.к. 1-2 3-4 и тд это диапазоны, если можно выразиться отрезки [], т.е. для всех крайних результатов диапазона будут одинаковые значения, как и для их содержимого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение столбца С для нижней границы диапазона:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИНДЕКС(B2:B21;ПОИСКПОЗ(D1;A2:A21))=E1;ИНДЕКС(C2:C21;ПОИСКПОЗ(D1;A2:A21));"нет")
```

Значение столбца С для верхней границы диапазона:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИНДЕКС(B2:B21;ПОИСКПОЗ(D1;A2:A21)+1-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:A21;D1))=E1;ИНДЕКС(C2:C21;ПОИСКПОЗ(D1;A2:A21)+1-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:A21;D1));"нет")
```

где *D1* - число, *E1* - условие

Осталось проверить полученные значения на равенство.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
-------------------------------
```

**Формулы, показанные выше, работают со значениями столбца А, расположенными по возрастанию.**

**Для несортированных даннных** формула сложнее:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(A2:A20<=D1;ЕСЛИ(A3:A21>=D1;ЕСЛИ(B2:B20=E1;ЕСЛИ(B3:B21=E1;ЕСЛИ(C2:C20=C3:C21;СТРОКА(A2:A20)))))))
```

Формула вводится, как формула массива (*Ctrl+Shift+Enter*). Определяет нужную строку. Если подходящей нет, покажет ноль.

Можно было написать короче: вместо каскада ЕСЛИ применить логическое И:

```
(A2:A20<=D1)*(A3:A21>=D1)*(B2:B20=E1)*(B3:B21=E1)*(C2:C20=C3)
```

но в этом случае формула будет считать намного больше, а *ЕСЛИ* позволяют отсекать лишние вычисления.

Результат используется для поиска значения в столбце С:

```
=ЕСЛИ(D2;ИНДЕКС(C2:C20;D2-1);"нет")
```

где *D2* - формула определения строки.

Comment: применил данный ответ, но т.к. вопрос поставил неправильно. см UPD

Comment: Фомулы будут работать и с учетом последнего изменения условия задачи. Или я не понял, что нужно.

Comment: я плохо выразился, если с учетом обновления, взять число 51800, то на выходе я получу значение II по нижнему диапазону и по верхнему, а необходимо III. Т.к. вторая строчка на обработку идет раньше, чем 3-я, то наверное и получается II?

Comment: См. рисунок, добавленный к ответу. Результат - III. Если Вы о том, что 51800 Не попадает ни в один из диапазонов (пример до UPD), то и здесь порядок - две формулы покажут разные значения: II и III. И срвнение этих значений покажет, что число вывалилось за границы.

Comment: ![Кликабельно. В зеленом диапазоне лежит число, но значение от 51746](http://joxi.ru/l2ZlvXYh84wOBr).

Comment: Вы показали неправильные исходные данные. Здесь значения столбца А идут по возрастанию, на картинке по ссылке значения не сортированы. Для ПОИСКПОЗ с неточным соответствием значения нужно размещать по возрастанию.

Comment: если их отсортировать нарушатся диапазоны

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45479/discussion-between-grm-and-vikttur).

Comment: Не стоит, дополнил ответ вариантом для несортированных данных